# Rotating a D3DXVECTOR3 around a specific point

Tags: vector, matrix, direct3d, directx-10, rotational-matrices

This is probably a pretty simple thing but my knowledge of direct x is just not up to par with what I'm trying to achieve.

For the moment I am trying to create a vehicle that moves around on terrain. I am attempting to make the vehicle recognize the terrain by creating a square (4 D3DXVECTOR3 points) around the vehicle who's points each detect the height of the terrain and adjust the vehicle accordingly.

The vehicle is a simple object derived from Microsoft sample code. It has a world matrix, coordinates, rotations etc.

What I am trying to achieve is to make these points move along with the vehicle, turning when it does so they can detect the difference in height. This requires me to update the points each time the vehicle moves but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get them to rotate properly.

So In summary I am looking for a simple way to rotate a vector about an origin (my vehicles coordinates).

These points are situated near the vehicle wheels so if it worked they would stay there regardless of the vehicles y -axis rotation.

Heres What Ive tryed:

```
D3DXVECTOR3 vec;
D3DXVec3TransformCoord(&vectorToHoldTransformation,&SquareTopLeftPoint,&matRotationY);
SquareTopLeftPoint = vec;
```

This resulted in the point spinning madly out of control and leaving the map.

```
xRot = VehicleCoordinateX + cos(RotationY) * (SquareTopleftX - VehicleCoordinateX) - sin(RotationY) * (SquareTopleftZ - VehicleCoordinateZ);
yRot = VehicleCoordinateZ + sin(RotationY) * (SquareTopleftX - VehicleCoodinateX) + cos(RotationY) * (SquareToplefteZ - VehicleCoordinateZ);
```

BoxPoint refers to the vector I am attempting to rotate.
Vehicle is of course the origin of rotation
RotationY is the amount it has rotated.

This is the code for 1 of 4 vectors in this square but I assume once I get 1 write the rest are just copy-paste.

No matter what I try the point either does not move or spirals out of control under leaving the map all-together.

Here is a snippet of my object class

```
class Something
{
public:
    float x, y, z;
    float speed;          
    float rx, ry, rz;     
    float sx, sy, sz;

    float width;
    float length; 
    float frameTime;


    D3DXVECTOR3 initVecDir;
    D3DXVECTOR3 currentVecDir;

    D3DXMATRIX       matAllRotations;
    D3DXMATRIX       matRotateX;
    D3DXMATRIX       matRotateY;
    D3DXMATRIX       matRotateZ;
    D3DXMATRIX       matTranslate;
    D3DXMATRIX       matWorld;  
    D3DXMATRIX       matView;           
    D3DXMATRIX       matProjection;
    D3DXMATRIX       matWorldViewProjection;

//these points represent a box that is used for collision with terrain.
        D3DXVECTOR3 frontLeftBoxPoint;
        D3DXVECTOR3 frontRightBoxPoint;
        D3DXVECTOR3 backLeftBoxPoint;
        D3DXVECTOR3 backRightBoxPoint;
    }
```

I was thinking it might be possible to do this using D3DXVec3TransformCoord

```
D3DXMatrixTranslation(&matTranslate, origin.x,0,origin.z);
D3DXMatrixRotationY(&matRotateY, ry);
D3DXMatrixTranslation(&matTranslate2,width,0,-length);
matAllRotations = matTranslate * matRotateY * matTranslate2;


D3DXVECTOR3 newCoords;
D3DXVECTOR3 oldCoords = D3DXVECTOR3(x,y,z);

D3DXVec3TransformCoord(&newCoords, &oldCoords, &matAllRotations);
```

Comment: Without knowing how your matrices are formed, it is impossible to know what you're actually doing with that code. Could you post a bit more on how you compute these matrices? Additionally, "BoxPoint" doesn't appear in your code.

Comment: I posted some of the object code, maybe this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that what I need to do was

1. Translate by -origin.
2. rotate
3. Translate by origin.

What I was doing was

1. Move to origin
2. Rotate
3. Translate by length/width

Thought it was the same.

```
    D3DXMATRIX matTranslate2;
D3DXMatrixTranslation(&matTranslate,-origin.x,0,-origin.z);
D3DXMatrixRotationY(&matRotateY,ry);
D3DXMatrixTranslation(&matTranslate2,origin.x,0,origin.z);
//D3DXMatrixRotationAxis(&matRotateAxis,&origin,ry);

D3DXMATRIX matAll = matTranslate * matRotateY * matTranslate2;

D3DXVECTOR4 newCoords;
D3DXVECTOR4 oldCoords = D3DXVECTOR4(x,y,z,1);

D3DXVec4Transform(&newCoords,&oldCoords,&matAll);
//D3DXVec4TransformCoord(&newCoords, &oldCoords, &matAll);

return newCoords;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your code I can't say what it does exactly, however one 'easy' way to think about this problem if you know the angle of the heading of your vehicle in world coordinates is to represent your points in a manner such that the center of the vehicle is at the origin, use a simple [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) to rotate it around the vehicle according to the heading, and then add your vehicle's center to the resulting coordinates.

```
x = vehicle_center_x + cos(heading) * corner_x - sin(heading) * corner_y
y = vehicle_center_y - sin(heading) * corner_x + cos(heading) * corner_y
```

Keep in mind that corner_x and corner_y are expressed in coordinates relative to the vehicle -- NOT relative to the world.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I represent the box coordinates relative to the vehicle? I need the box coordinates in world space or I cant use it for its current purpose. I added some information on the vehicle class is that helps.

Comment: Is it possible to use D3DXVec3TransformCoord to do this?

Comment: From what I gather, you want a box that remains fixed relative to the vehicle. That is, in the object's local space the coordinates are fixed. To get the corners' world space coordinates you transform the coordinates relative to the vehicle into world space. So, you could multiply your local coordinates for the box by your world transform using the appropriate D3DXVec call. The problem with that is you may or may not want your corners to move up/down as the vehicle tilts forward/back, for example. That's why I suggested the above method.

Comment: Hmm that would explain why when ive tried something similar the box points would not stay with the vehicle. I was using world space coordinates. Ill give this a try again

Comment: I see above you have used X and Y. Keep in mind that for what I am doing Im purely rotating objects on the ground. So around the y axis at y=0. I tried adapting this by changing y for z but now my cups are doing some sort of weird dance around the car. This may be getting rotation mixed up.. Any chance U can explain what Im doing wrong?